# git-svn clone within a specific revision range

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm trying to use git-svn to import a brunch of projects hosted in a svn server.

The repository structure looks as follows

```
root
    [...]
    project 1
        trunk
        branches
        tags
    project 2
        trunk
        branches
        tags
    [...]
```

what I want to achieve is to import all the svn history of *project1* and *project2*.

Unfortunately the origin repository contains more than 2 million revisions... a full git-svn clone would last forever.

So I retrieved the first and last revision of my two projects and tried to run

```
git svn clone -s https://svn.bansel.it/h2o/ \
    --include-paths='^[/](Project1|Project2)' \
    -r1788813:1792593
```

where **1788813** is the first revision and **1792593** is the last i'm intrested in.

When I exexute the command it runs withot error. I also notice some network traffic, but if later on i try a to run `git svn log`

```
$ git svn log
fatal: bad revision 'HEAD'
rev-list --first-parent --pretty=medium HEAD --: command returned error: 128
```

also the target repository seems completely empty.
Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

I will not be able to shut down the SVN repository after the import, so i will need a bidirectional synchronization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `clone` command is wrong.

`-s` with URL `https://svn.bansel.it/h2o/` tells `git-svn` to look at `https://svn.bansel.it/h2o/trunk`, `https://svn.bansel.it/h2o/tags` and `https://svn.bansel.it/h2o/branches`. There it does not find anything and thus your clone does not contain any commits and thus no `HEAD` reference.

It might be a good idea to have two git repositories, one for each of your projects, so two `clone` commands like `git svn clone -s https://svn.bansel.it/h2o/Project1/ -r1788813:1792593` and `git svn clone -s https://svn.bansel.it/h2o/Project2/ -r1788813:1792593`.

Or if you want both in the same repository within different remotes you can do the `clone` commands with the same git repository as target, using `--prefix=origin-project1` and `--prefix=origin-project2` to get the two projects in two separate remotes. But I really think you should use separate Git repos for those two.

**Note:** Be aware that you also need the revision argument for each subsequent `fetch` as far as I remember, but I might be wrong, I usually don't constrain the revisions for `git-svn`.